# MYSQL query to select users from a table who have the most entries

Tags: mysql, count

I currently have a table in this structure:

[image]

I want to be able to select the *top 3* `user_id`'s from the table according to the amount of entries, so the three user's with the most rows in the table. (it only shows the user with the id 111 in the screenshot below but there are obviously a lot more entries in this table).
Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
select user_id,count(user_id) as cnt from table
group by user_id
order by cnt desc
limit 0,3;
```

Comment: remember that this query will not handle any tie, consider this records (*returned*) `userID, totalCount`,`1, 5`, `2, 5`,`3, 5`,`4, 5`,`5, 5`

Answer (score 1):

```
select user_id, count(*) from table group by user_id order by count(*) desc limit 0,3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query, Grouping by userid, sorting by hghest entries and limiting the result to top 3 results.

```
select user_id, count(sickness_submission_id) as entries from <table Name> group by user_id order by entries  desc limit 0, 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this [Select Top n Records Predicate Example](http://www.blueclaw-db.com/accessquerysql/select_top.htm)

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
SELECT COUNT(user_id) AS Number-of-entries, user_id FROM table GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY count(user_id) DESC LIMIT 3;
```

Breakdown:
COUNT(user_id) counts all user_id's (and gives it the output heading "Number-of-entries").
GROUP BY shows every user_id only once.
ORDER BY DESC prints the result with number of entries, most to least.
LIMIT 3 shows only the first three results.